# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drivername'

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I get this error when i start my app. Obviously it has something with SQLAlchemy. I 've been working this example with help of Corey Schaffer Flask tutorial.

```
> File "C:\Users\Matea\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\Matea\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Matea\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\Matea\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\Matea\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Matea\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Matea\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\Matea\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\Matea\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Matea\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "C:\Users\Matea\myblog\myblog\main\routes.py", line 11, in home
posts = Post.query.order_by(Post.date_posted.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=5)
File "C:\Users\Matea\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 514, in __get__
return type.query_class(mapper, session=self.sa.session())
File "C:\Users\Matea\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\scoping.py", line 74, in __call__
return self.registry()
File "C:\Users\Matea\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 1001, in __call__
return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())
File "C:\Users\Matea\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2950, in __call__
return self.class_(**local_kw)
File "C:\Users\Matea\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 143, in __init__
bind = options.pop('bind', None) or db.engine
File "C:\Users\Matea\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 877, in engine
return self.get_engine()
File "C:\Users\Matea\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 896, in get_engine
return connector.get_engine()
File "C:\Users\Matea\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 556, in get_engine
self._sa.apply_driver_hacks(self._app, info, options)
File "C:\Users\Matea\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 830, in apply_driver_hacks
if info.drivername.startswith('mysql'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drivername'
```

here is some code:
This is from my **init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_mail import Mail
from myblog.config import Config


db = SQLAlchemy()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'users.login'
login_manager.login_message_category = 'info'
mail = Mail()


def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    db.init_app(app)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)

    from myblog.users.routes import users
    from myblog.posts.routes import posts
    from myblog.main.routes import main
    from myblog.errors.handlers import errors
    app.register_blueprint(users)
    app.register_blueprint(posts)
    app.register_blueprint(main)
    app.register_blueprint(errors)

    return app
```

this piece code is from config.py

```
import os


class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL')
    MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.googlemail.com'
    MAIL_PORT = 587
    MAIL_USE_TLS = True
    MAIL_USERNAME = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
    MAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
```

I hope that you will help me and if something is missing,please tell me, Thank you!

Comment: Both the error messages are related to your engine configuration.

Comment: Can you explain me what that means?

Answer (score 5):

if you have correctly set the environment variable in the **.bash_proflie**

```
    export EMAIL_USER='youremail@gmail.com'
    export EMAIL_PASS='Yourpassword'
    export SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='sqlite:///site.db'
    export SECRET_KEY='secretkeyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

then try restarting your computer.
if it still fails 
*Try to create the database in python *

```
from your yourflaskapp import db
db.create_all()
```

*If your app is in blueprints*

```
    use from yourapp import create_app
    app = create_app()
    app.app_context().push()
```

> Always refresh your text editor and the terminal after making changes.
>   Also try to make sure you are running your app in the right directory.

for more info visit on blueprints use

> http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/contexts/

Answer (score 2):

@Ivan M, I'm going through the same tutorial and had this problem as well. This happens because instructor moved the database URI and other params into environment variables (see [Part 11](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wfx4YBzg16s&list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH&index=11) at about minute 27). It is a safety measure and good dev practice.
In order to make things work through config file, revert the changes in init.py and update config.py to have the direct link instead of square brackets:
`SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///site.db'`
UPD: same goes for `SECRET_KEY` and other params you wish to hard code:
`SECRET_KEY = '5791628bb0b13ce0c676dfde280ba245'`

Answer (score 1):

I was following the same tutorial and got into this issue while setting up the `config.py` file as guided by the instructor.

#### Case with me

I was using PyCharm. PyCharm has the functionality to set project-specific `environment variables`. This means you can set `environment variables` w/o modifying `.bash` or `.bash_profile`, etc. files.

#### Mistake I Did

While setting up `environment variables`, we aren't supposed to have:

1. Spaces before and after the variable name
2. Quotes surrounding the value, for example:

   - `sqlite:///site.db` ✅
   - `'sqlite:///site.db'`❌
3. Quotes surrounding the variable name, for example:

   - `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` ✅
   - `'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'`❌
4. Spaces before and after the `=`
5. Spaces before and after the value

> Note: If you are setting `environment variables` by modifying or creating `.bash_profile` or similar files, some of the above five points might not apply.

*I did the 1st and 2nd mistake. So, silly.*

Namaste

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps. I was running into the same problems.
I put print(f'From init {Config.**dict**}') just below def create_app(config=Config): in **init**.py & can see config.py attributes from a VS Code bash terminal or from a standalone bash session - all works OK I was running python run.py from Windows terminal using powershell. Works OK from cmd with setting.bat file run first

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issues with that but
installing python-dotenv it solves the issues

`pip3 install python3-dotenv`
or else if it doesn't then the terminal suggest to go with sudo
try with sudo as admin then it'll

it'll work after installing env

and i'll suggest one more thing....like if any guy didn't setup the environment then setup first in bashprofile for both the 'EMAIL_USER' and for 'EMAIL_PASS' and same goes for those SECRET KEY and SQLALCHEMY
to do this you have to go to your nano editor and make these environment

for LINUX

```
nano .bash_profile   (enter then it'll take you to the nano editor)
export DB_USER="Your email"
export DB_PASS="Your password"
export SECRET_KEY="your secret key"
export SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI="sqlite:///site.db"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bash do this

```
export SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='sqlite:///site.db'
```

and in Windows Set

`SECRET_KEY`

`xxxx14cae56bab7xxxxxxxxxxxxx`

`SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI`

`sqlite:///site.db`

save everything then close terminal and close editor and restart your terminal and editor. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case with pyCharm only hardcoding helped or a better solution is:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL')
```

And put your vars in .env file.
.env

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=sqlite:///site.db
```

Answer (score -1):

Had this issue many times. The reason was Python doesn't recognize your `.env` file.

You can install `python-dotenv` by `pipenv install python-dotenv`.

and then
`SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL')`
will work.